# create a window chrome with an exception in back

Tags: background, google-chrome-extension

I'd just like to create a new window from the background page and put it in back. I tried focused:false but it doesn't seem to make the trick. I tried to save the previous windowId and tabId and update it after having creating the new window but it doesn't solve the problem neither.

Do you know how we can do that?

Here is my code:

```
function saveTabId() {
    // Get the current tab
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
        if (tab != 'undefined') {
            if (tab.windowId != windowId) {
                currentTabId = tab.id;
                currentWindowId = tab.windowId;
            }

            chrome.windows.create({url:"http://www.google.com", width:100,     height:100, top:0, left:0, focused:false}, function() {

              chrome.tabs.get(currentTabId, function(tab) {
                chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, {}, function(w) {
                  chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {selected:true});
                });
              });

            });

        }

    });
}
```

I launched this code at the beginning of background.html and when I refresh the extension, the window is on top of the extensions tab.

P.S: something more strange the window is on top of the extensions tab and when I change tab in this window, the new window stays on top of the other one even if I click and type text in the other one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, here is the code I'm using now. The problem in the code of the question was the focus to the other window before updating it. It is strange, when you focus on a window, it doesn't show it on top of the others.

```
function focusTab(tabId) {
    chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(tab) {
        chrome.windows.update(tab.windowId, {}, function(w) {
          chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {selected:true});
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it kind of working, but popup window is still showing up for a moment before going underneath the current window:

```
chrome.windows.create({url:"http://www.google.com", width:100, height:100, top:0, left:0, focused:false}, function() {
    chrome.windows.update(currentWindowId, {focused:true});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know if it is possible to have it directly under an other one... I just add in the next answer, the focus on the good tab but it is not necessarly in fact :)